# Is IPC Communication is an alternative for API in electron apps?

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application, node-sqlite3

Currently I'm learning to build  electron app , I'm just trying to figure out if IPC Communication is the right way to access local SQLLITE db from front end and make it act like a API , or is there any other correct way to handle it , without overusing the CPU resources.

This is my scenario , if the app is offline , I need a way to communicate to local SQLLITE  db and process some inputs and outputs  like how normally API's do .

Comment: It's not clear how you understand the term "API". What are "*make it act like a API*" and "*like how normally API's do*" supposed to mean?

Comment: I mean how typical rest API Works , When requested , it does some methods and returns certain values , it may either be a db request or normal simple data manipulation.

Comment: You use background process to talk with Sqlitedb and then use IPC from your frontend or renderer process to talk to the background process. Generally that's how renderers communicate with background processes.

Comment: The IPC channel is designed to establish the communication channel between the main process and the renderer process in the electron app.

And IPC is also an API from electron. Seems like you understand API as a kinda function that makes the data connection between server and client.

Comment: @jeffrey Yes, you can implement a rest-like API on top of IPC messaging just like you can implement it on top of HTTP